# Spring Websocket integration with Kafka

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-websocket, spring-kafka

**I'm trying to send consumed Kafka data to frontend (JavaScript) via Spring-Websockets in a Spring MVC project.**

To establish the communication between the server and client, I have the following.

**Client (app.js)**

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/kafka-data-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.send("/app/fetchData");
        stompClient.subscribe('/data/records', function (message) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(message.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

**Server (KafkaController.java)**

```
@Controller
public class KafkaController {

    @MessageMapping("/fetchData")
    @SendTo("/data/records")
    public String fetchMetrics() {
        //...
    }
}
```

To consume data from a specific Kafka topic I'm using @KafkaListener annotation as follows:

```
public class KafkaReceiver {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        MyRecord m = new MyRecord(new Long(record.offset()), record.key().toString(), record.value().toString());
           //...
    }
}
```

And I have a proper KafkaConfig class with all the necessary beans ([like explained here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#__kafkalistener_annotation)).

### How can I send data from **`receive`** method to KafkaController's **`fetchMetrics`** (and consequently to the websocket) on each incoming/consumed message?

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should inject `SimpMessagingTemplate` into the `KafkaReceiver` and use it from the `receive()` method:

```
 this.template.convertAndSend("/data/records", m);
```

See more info in the Spring Framework [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-handle-send).

Comment: hey! thanks very much for the answer. I got this error now: `SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [org.apache.kafka.clients.NodeApiVersions]
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.NodeApiVersions.apiVersionToText(NodeApiVersions.java:167)`
Any ideas?